# overflow:scroll in foreignObject not work in d3 force layout

Tags: d3.js, scroll, overflow

I'm using d3js for my work. In my case, the problem is that the scrollbars in foreignobject donot work. I 've searched this but there's no succesful solutions. One thing is that the scrollbar worked well before the foreignobject was put in force layout. I dont understand why? This is my code and 
many thanks for all the supports!

```
<div id="main" style="width:800; height:800">
</div>
<script>
var nodes=[
  {"name": "david"},
  {"name": "beckham"}
];
var links=[
    {"s":"david", "t":"beckham"}
    ];
var graph={};

graph['nodes']=nodes;
graph['links']=links;

graph.links.forEach(function(link){
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(node){
            if(link.s === node.name)
                link.source = node;
            else link.target = node; 


        }); 
    }); 

var svg = d3.select("#main").append('svg:svg')

    .attr("id","main_svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 800);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-300)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .size([800, 800])
    .nodes(d3.values(graph.nodes))
    .on("tick", tick)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();

var group = svg.append("g");

var path=group.selectAll("path").data(force.links());
path.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("id",function(d,i) { return "linkId_" + i; })
        .style("stroke-width",1);

var node = group.selectAll("rect").data(force.nodes());
node.enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class","node")
                .attr("width",10)
                .attr("height",10)
                .style("fill","red");

var forobj = group.selectAll("foreignObject").data(force.nodes());              
forobj.enter().append("foreignObject")
                        .attr("class","forobj")
                        .attr("id",function(d){return d.name;})
                        .attr("width",400)
                        .attr("height",150)
                        .append("xhtml:body")
                        .style("display", function(d){
                                return (d.name === "david") ? "inline-block":"none";
                            })
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("class",function(d){return "class" + d.name;})
                        .attr("id",function(d){return "div" + d.name;})
                        .style("width",300)
                        .style("height",100)
                        .style("overflow","scroll")
                        .html("<table style=\"width:400; height:200; background-color:#0FC\"><tr><td>table contents</td><td>table contents</td><td>table contents</td><td>table contents</td><td>table contents</td><td>table contents</td></tr></table>");



function tick(e) {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + 
                d.source.x + "," + 
                d.source.y + "A" + 
                dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
                d.target.x + "," + 
                d.target.y;
        });
    forobj.attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate(" + (d.x + 20) + "," + (d.y + 20) + ")"; });
    node.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
</script>
```

Comment: [This thread](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/why-no-scroll-bar-when-using-a-div-within-a-div/) should help.

Comment: I've seen the scrollbars work well in Firefox, but not work in Chrome. The thread is still useful for me when using static position elements. I don't understand why the scrollbars don't work in Chrome. Thanks Lars!